# Obtaining z-buffer(depth) informaiton from dicom file in python

Tags: python, dicom, depth

I have a set of dicom images(contains 160 .dcm files). I can visualize a **single** file by the following python code:

```
import pydicom as dicom
import os
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = "./myfiles/MR000130.dcm";

dataset = dicom.dcmread(filename)

plt.imshow(dataset.pixel_array, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
```

My question is:

1. How do I visualize these whole bunch of volumetric data as a single picture?
2. Is there any way to obtain the z-buffer information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the file. There is stuff in the DICOM apart from pixel data. See it with
`print(dataset._pretty_str)`.

It might be `dataset.SliceLocation`.

We can't tell you how to change 3D to 2D. You could read all the slices, and then reslice in other planes. You could do some fancy segmentation and render surfaces in 3D. You need to decide what is most appropriate for your case.